# utf-8 decoding issue - python

Tags: python, base64, spotify

I'm following a video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WAmEZBEeNmg&t=847s) in order to interact with spotify by python

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import base64
from requests import post
import json

load_dotenv()

client_id = os.getenv("CLIENT_ID")
client_secret = os.getenv("CLIENT_SECRET")


def get_token():
    auth_string = client_id + ":" + client_secret
    auth_bytes = auth_string.encode("utf-8")
    auth_base64 = str(base64.b64decode(auth_bytes), "utf-8")

    url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + auth_base64,
        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
    data = {"grant_type": "client_credentials"}
    result = post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    json_result = json.loads(result.content)
    token = json_result["access_token"]
    return token

token = get_token()
print(token)
```

And I recive this error

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 0: invalid continuation byte`

Comment: What part of your code is throwing the error?

Comment: which line lead to the error, please paste more detail info about the error

Answer (score 1):

With the requests libary, to get the JSON response of a query you use:

```
result.json()
```

This will return a dictionary object, if the response contains a JSON response.
You do not need to use the JSON libary to convert it to a dictionary. It does that for you.

However, in your code sample you used:

```
result.content
```

This will not return a dictionary and instead returns a bytes-like object.
The error you are encountering is most likely occuring when you are using `json.loads` to load `result.content` as a dictionary, however it (may not) contain JSON-like data at all hence it will show an error.

**I may be wrong though, and this error is showing up somewhere else. Your question doesn't provide enough context where the error is showing up.**

Answer (score 0):

This code will work

##### Demo code

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import base64
from requests import post
import json

load_dotenv()

client_id = os.getenv("CLIENT_ID")
client_secret = os.getenv("CLIENT_SECRET")

def get_token():
    b64_bytes = (client_id + ":" + client_secret).encode('ascii')
    auth_base64 = str(base64.b64encode(b64_bytes), 'UTF-8')
    
    url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + auth_base64,
        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
    data = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        'scope' : 'playlist-modify-private,playlist-modify-public'
    }
    result = post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    json_result = json.loads(result.content)
    token = json_result["access_token"]
    return token

token = get_token()
print(token)
```

##### Result

[image]

##### Set environment variable

In Windows

```
SET CLIENT_ID=<your client id>
SET CLIENT_SECRET=<your client secret>
```

In Linux/Mac

```
EXPORT CLIENT_ID=<your client id>
EXPORT CLIENT_SECRET=<your client secret>
```

This version also works

```py
    auth_string = f'{client_id}:{client_secret}'
    auth_bytes = auth_string.encode('utf-8')
    auth_base64 = str(base64.b64encode(auth_bytes), 'utf-8')
```